# Making health reduce by 1 every second

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, reduce

I'm programming a tamagotci style game and I need to health by one, every second. I already have a score number in place that is changed when you feed the target. I would be incredibly grateful if someone could give me a hand in editing the current code I have at the moment, to reduce health by 1 every second. Here is my code if anyone needs to see it;

```
        health=100
        txtform.font = "Arial";  
        txtform.color = 0x000000;
        txtform.size = 24;
        txtform.bold = true; 
        healthdisplay.defaultTextFormat=txtform;
        addChild(healthdisplay);
        healthdisplay.text=("Health: " + health)
        healthdisplay.x=75
        healthdisplay.y=-20
        healthdisplay.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;

    }

    public function IncreaseHealth(points:int){
        health+=points
        healthdisplay.text=("Health: " + health)
        healthdisplay.defaultTextFormat=txtform;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function `DecreaseHealth()` that you call every second. Something like:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000); // 1 second = 1000 milliseconds.
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, DecreaseHealth);

timer.start();
```

Where `DecreaseHealth()` has the following signature:

```
function DecreaseHealth(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    health -= 1;
    // Do printing or whatever else here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's probably someting totally oblivious to me but after I inputted your code I get the compiler error "Access of possibly undefined property TIMER through a reference with static type Class."

Comment: @user3179788 Try the code sample now, I bet it was complaining because I had `Timer.TIMER` instead of `TimerEvent.TIMER`.

Comment: Well it complies now, thanks! I've added it to my Avatar function to try and decrease the value of Health, but no luck0. i'm getting the output as ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Avatar/DecreaseHealth(). Expected 0, got 1.
 at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
 at flash.utils::Timer/tick() Any ideas?

Comment: If you read the error carefully, it says 'Argument count mismatch'. This means `DecreaseHealth()` has too many or too few arguments. I know why, I'll edit the code. The event listener must have an argument for a `TimerEvent`.

Comment: I seem to be confusing myself trying to get your code to work at the moment the function looks like this;                      public function DecreaseHealth(event:TimerEvent):void
  {
     var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
  timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, DecreaseHealth);
  timer.start();
  } Am I doing something wrong? Thanks again for helping me solve this.

Comment: No, all that timer code goes **outside** `DecreaseHealth()`. I'll edit one more time to make it more clear, but that's all you're getting from me. :) Please mark as the answer.